# print formatted table from csv

Tags: java, csv

I want to read a csv file and print it formatted on console

This is my code to print

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

   // use comma as separator
   String[] fields = line.split(",");

   for(String field : fields) {
      System.out.print(field);
   }
   System.out.println();
}
```

but the table is not formatted, i want each cell to be printed exactly under the column name (each column must start in the same place) and i want space between columns, is that possible and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) to print same spaces each time, for example:

```
                                                   //1234567890123456789012345
System.out.print(String.format("%25s", field));    //       right aligned text
System.out.print(String.format("%-25s", field));   //left aligned text
```

As pointed by [Jopp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984823/joop-eggen), same can be achieved with printf also:

```
System.out.printf("%-25s", field);
```

Comment: `"| %-25s"` for left-aligned text. `System.out.printf` suffices